# Dark Mode on Microsoft Excel Mac?

Tags: ms-office

The white cell background is a source of eye-strain.

Is there a way to enable dark background for cells?

I do not want to color the cell background as black, since this document is shared on both Windows and Mac computers. I understand that there is a dark theme for Excel Windows.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. You could always use the inverse video Mac Accessibility option.

Comment: That's too bad. I guess I'll have to use that workaround